log4net:ERROR ConfigureFromXml called with null 'element' parameter for Postgres SQL
when we are trying to insert log files in the postgres sql we are facing the issue:
log4net:ERROR ConfigureFromXml called with null 'element' parameter.
In this code we are trying to insert log files in postgres SQL using Asp.net core.
Under configservice() code in startup.cs file:
return services.AddAbp<DTSWebHostModule>(options =>
{
    //Configure Log4Net logging
    options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
        f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig(_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()
            ? "log4net.config"
            : "log4net.Production.config")

    );

});

code in log4net.config file:
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
            <connectionType value="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql" />
            <connectionString value="User ID=postgres;Password=password;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=DTSPowerToolsPostgres;Pooling=true;" />
            <commandText value="INSERT INTO public.log ( thread, log_level, logger, message, exception) 
                      VALUES ( @thread, @log_level, @Source, @message, @exception)" />
            <commandType value="Text" />

            <bufferSize value="1" />

            <lossy value="false" />

            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@thread" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_level" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="50" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%level" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@Source" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@message" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="4000" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@exception" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="2000" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
            </parameter>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <appSettings>
                <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
            </appSettings>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>

</configuration>

Check for another error causing here:
This code is in log4net.config file tried using below code for datetime parameter to insert logs into DataBase.
In log4net.config File:
1) <parameter>
<parameterName value="@log_date" />
<dbType value="DateTime" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.RawUtcTimeStampLayout" />

This code works and inserts Logs into DB. But, an exception mentioned in the screenshot is appearing.
2) <parameter>
<parameterName value="@log_date" />
<dbType value="TimestampTz" /> <!-- PostgreSQL timestamp with time zone -->
<layout type="log4net.Layout.RawUtcTimeStampLayout" />

This code didn't work and not inserting Logs into DB. But, No exception is appaering.
3) <parameter>
<parameterName value="@log_date" />
<dbType value="Timestamp" /> <!-- PostgreSQL timestamp without time zone -->
<layout type="log4net.Layout.RawUtcTimeStampLayout" />

This code didn't work and not inserting Logs into DB. But, No exception is appaering.
screenshot, Click Here..
This screenshot says that, The Postgres SQL uses TimeStamp with Time Zone but, we are using "DateTime" dbType with of layout type Kind=UTC. which, the DateTime can't be written with different types
But in the first code, we are making use of DateTime which is .NET object which is causing the error and inserting Logs into DB.
In the Second code, we are making use of TimestampTz which is Postgre SQL DB type which is not causing the error and not inserting Logs into DB.
For the Third code, which is Same issue as Second code(above).
Note: If there is no DateTime parameter in log4net.config file also causing the same exception as in screenshot.
The following Script is for Postgres SQL table creation:
CREATE TABLE log(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
log_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
thread VARCHAR(255),
log_level VARCHAR(50),
logger VARCHAR(255),
message TEXT,
exception TEXT

);
Hope, this helps you understand the problem. We are unable to share the code using new repo. Thank you.

The root node in the log4net.config configuration file is <log4net></log4net>. So you need to modify the log4net.config file as follows.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <connectionType value="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection, Npgsql" />
        <connectionString value="User ID=postgres;Password=password;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=DTSPowerToolsPostgres;Pooling=true;" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO public.log ( thread, log_level, logger, message, exception) 
                  VALUES ( @thread, @log_level, @Source, @message, @exception)" />
        <commandType value="Text" />

        <bufferSize value="1" />

        <lossy value="false" />

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@thread" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_level" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="50" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%level" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@Source" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@message" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="4000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@exception" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="2000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
        </parameter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <appSettings>
            <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
        </appSettings>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>


Hello, Thank you for the response. This code works with a time exception in Asp.net zero(actual framework).  The error is             System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', consider using 'timestamp with time zone'. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array, range, or multirange. (Parameter 'value')'
Please check this.

Tried using other dbType values like Timestamp, TimeStampTZ  (If used as dbType values in config file, No exception but, logs are not inserting into DB. Same for Timestamp also) and kept the date as auto generate in DB but, the exception keeps coming.

@vprudhvi The format of configuration file is correct now, but we have encountered other problems. Please guide us on how to reproduce the problem, or provide a repo (create a brand new project without any sensitive information or code) that can reproduce the problem. I am willing to investigate it further.

Thank you for your interest. We can't provide you the code using a repo. But, I have explained it using a screenshot and code.  This maybe mainly related to .NET objects and Postgres SQL DB Types. Please refer the Question for the screenshot and related code. Thank you.

@vprudhvi Try to change the DateTime object like this DateTime dateTimeValue = yourDateTimeValue.ToUniversalTime();  DateTime unspecifiedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeValue, DateTimeKind.Unspecified); before inserting the Postgres SQL DB. And waiting for your update.

Thank you. This code is working even with "DateTime" dbtype value and logs are inserting into DB but, our application is not working properly. Any code changes related to DateTime in the ".cs" files causing login issues with an error, "Internal server error occurred".

@vprudhvi In the development environment, use app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(), and in the production environment, use app.UseExceptionHandler() to catch the exception. Let's take a look at what happened.

Here, I recieved this in the console, ERROR:
{code: 0, message: 'An internal error occurred during your request!', details: null, validationErrors: null}

How about using try..catch ? Or could you kindly check the Eventviewer, maybe we can find more details.

I found this in the logs inserted into Postgres SQL DB. Please check this,                       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', consider using 'timestamp with time zone'. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array, range, or multirange. (Parameter 'value')

@vprudhvi ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_column TYPE timestamp with time zone; 

@vprudhvi Try to change the column type manually in your database. Please noted, this is another issue, not same as orginal one.

@vprudhvi If the issue still occurs, please let me know, I am willing to help you check it. If you can create a new post, it will be great.

Yes, I will create a new post. Thank you.

Hi, @Jason Pan Please check this link for the new post,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79101025/log4net-error-code-0-message-an-internal-error-occurred-during-your-reques

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Will check it next Monday, thanks for your understanding.
