log4net ERROR: {code: 0, message: 'An internal error occurred during your request!', details: null, validationErrors: null} in .NET core
I tried to login after adding log4net to create logs in the Postgres SQL Database but, failed to login.
The issue is "ERROR: {code: 0, message: 'An internal error occurred during your request!', details: null, validationErrors: null}" from the console.
This code is in log4net.config file, I tried using below code for datetime parameter to insert logs into DataBase.
In log4net.config File:
1) <parameter>
   <parameterName value="@log_date" />
   <dbType value="DateTime" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawUtcTimeStampLayout" />
   </parameter>

This code works and inserts Logs into DB. But, an exception mentioned in the Title is appearing which is causing login failure with a message, "An internal error occurred during your request!"
Note: If there is no DateTime parameter in log4net.config file also causing the same exception as in screenshot.
screenshot
Added this code to clear errors on the server side exception:
DateTime dateTimeValue = yourDateTimeValue.ToUniversalTime();  DateTime unspecifiedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeValue, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

The following Script is for Postgres SQL table creation:
CREATE TABLE log(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
log_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
thread VARCHAR(255),
log_level VARCHAR(50),
logger VARCHAR(255),
message TEXT,
exception TEXT
);

The Error maybe "DateTime" dbType in .NET object is not able to map with Postgres SQL.
Hope, this helps you understand the problem.

Hi vprudhvi，try to use DateTime dateTimeValue = yourDateTimeValue.ToUniversalTime();, instead of DateTime dateTimeValue = yourDateTimeValue.ToUniversalTime();  DateTime unspecifiedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeValue, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);.

If still has some error, please share with me, thanks

Hello @Jason Pan, After using DateTime dateTimeValue = yourDateTimeValue.ToUniversalTime(); results in the same error as in the screenshot(same error) in the Question.

Could you try to find code some things like :command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("log_date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz) { Value = utcDateTime }); ? Or share me the code snippet about excuting sql statement (DB INSERT).

I want to check how you perform the db operation, then we can explicitly specify the parameter type as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE using NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.TimestampTz.

@Jason Pan, Please check the connection in the given link :
link

Please change parameter @log_date like below  <parameter>     <parameterName value="@log_date" />     <dbType value="String" />     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">         <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}" />     </layout> </parameter>, and tell us if it works.

@JasonPan Hello, The Exception in the Screenshot is repeating again.

Hi @vprudhvi, ok, try to use provious setting in your config file, now we need to excute below sql statement ALTER TABLE log4netlogs ALTER COLUMN log_date TYPE timestamp with time zone;

@JasonPan sir, Same Exception again

Please be patient, let me review this case carefully.

Could you try to enable the Npgsql logging feature? I mean if we can print the sql statement before inserting datatbase, then we can copy/paste and excute it manually in database tools.

Because I'm not sure, does this have something to do with the driver version?
